# How to catch argument from a bash script and pass to a php script command

Tags: php, bash, shell

Is there any way to get a string from a bash file to a php script?

```
example:

bin/execute path_to_file
```

Then that `path_to_file` would then be piped to the php script or env file or what ever could be done to it.

I cant find any resources for it...

any help would be great

Comment: Are you asking about catching arguments when you call a PHP script or a bash script? Or is the question something else? It's pretty unclear at the moment.

Comment: Hi, catching arguments from a bash script then pass the argument to a php script @MagnusEriksson

Comment: how to catching arguments or howto pass to php script?

and can you get help from https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php